# Hyperbolic Functions, possible mistake in professors lecture.

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, hyperbolic-functions

I'm currently working through a boundary value problem in my PDEs course. When searching for eigenvalues and eigenfunctions, I referred to my notes from class.

The following is exactly what my professor had for our particular problem.

> $$\omega (x) = Ae^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Be^{-x\sqrt{-\lambda}} $$
>   Recall the hyperbolic functions:
>   $$ \sinh(z) = \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2} \\  \\ \cosh(z) = \frac{e^z+e^{-z}}{2} $$
>   Rewriting $\omega (x)$, 
>   $$ \omega (x) = C\cosh(x\sqrt{-\lambda}) + D\sinh(x\sqrt{-\lambda}) $$

In my attempt to figure out how my professor got the trigonometric version of $\omega$, I found that:

$$ \omega (x) = Ae^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}} + Be^{-x\sqrt{-\lambda}} $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} (ae^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}}+be^{-x\sqrt{-\lambda}}) + \frac{1}{2} (ae^{x\sqrt{-\lambda}}+be^{-x\sqrt{-\lambda}}) $$
$$ = 2E\cosh(x\sqrt{-\lambda}) $$

Where $a$, $b$, and $E$ are just arbitrary constants.

Am I missing something, or did my professor make a mistake? My bet is that there is something I'm missing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Write $e^t=\cosh t+\sinh t$ and $e^{-t}=\cosh t -\sinh t$.

In you derivation, how can you make $\cosh$ suddenly appear? There is nothing in the preceding line that allows you to do that.

Comment: My reasoning was as simple as $\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}a=a$.  Is this wrong?

Comment: @kosta It's true that $a=a/2+a/2$, but where did you write that you expression is equal to $K(e^t+e^{-t})$, so that you can replace the parenthesis by $\cosh t$? Don't you see the $a$ and $b$ before the exponentials? They are not equal... (and actually, from what you have written, $a=A$ and $b=B$).

Comment: ... I see what I did wrong, I made a stupid mistake and assumed that would work. I apologize for the elementary mistake, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kosta No worry. I'm happy if it helped.